# Format value for string typed large number in OpenAPI Specification

Tags: openapi, jsonschema, number-formatting

To represent large numbers in a JSON Schema with high precision, it is a common practice to represent them as a string type to avoid precision loss.

I am wondering if there is a typical `format` value to be used for this, like `numeric-string` for example.

```
properties:
 - pi_to_hundred_decimals:
     type: string
     format: numeric-string
     description: The value of pi to hundred decimal places.
```

Is this a common practice? Or the format should be only `numeric` or eventually something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` keyword is strictly an annotation for the data type defined. There are some schema validators that use the `format` keyword to extend additional validation on the value but this is not standard JSON Schema behavior.

You can make up any `format` value your heart desires but, unless you write a custom validation with your preferred validator, it doesn't really mean much to anyone else except you and your peers.

If you're interested in following a pseudo standard, OpenAPI maintains a [format registry](https://spec.openapis.org/registry/format/) where a number of format keywords are defined.